How to deploy acme challenge pod inside of the host network
In my AKS clsuter setup I have a firewall in between the Application Gateway and the AKS cluster, in order to route my requests comming into the application gateway to the AKS cluster I am using custom route table, but in order to apply it to the the pods deployed inside of the AKS I have to use host network configuration in my deployments.
Is it possible to configure the cert-manager Issuer to create acme http verification pods inside of the host network?
I have not seen this option in the offical documentation, but maybe I am missing something
https://cert-manager.io/docs/reference/api-docs/#acme.cert-manager.io/v1.ACMEChallengeSolverHTTP01IngressPodSpec
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: {{.Values.tls.stageIssuerName}}
  namespace: {{.Values.namespaces.certManager}}
spec:
  acme:
    email: {{.Values.certEmail}}
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: {{.Values.tls.stagePrivateKeyName}}
    solvers:
      - selector: { }
        http01:
          ingress:
            class: azure/application-gateway
          podTemplate:
            metadata:
              labels:
                azure.workload.identity/use: "true"
            spec:
              serviceAccountName: {{.Values.identities.certManager.serviceAccountName}}
              hostNetwork: true
              dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet


this sounds like more of an architectural change to solve in the cluster CNI layer, rather than specifically for one pod / cert-manager issuer. more details would help. are you using azure CNI ?
